# a list of similar objects

Tags: python, list

I needed to create a list of `None` objects and used this form

```
a = [None] *2
a[0] = 0
```

the value of `a` was:

```
[1, None]
```

however, when i tried the same thing with:

```
a = [{'elem' : 0}] * 2
```

and after that

```
a[1]['elem'] = 0
```

the value of `a` became:

```
[{'elem': 1}, {'elem': 1}]
```

can anyone help me understand the mechanism behind this?

Comment: How was it `[1, None]`? Shouldn't that be `[0, None]`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters But that question doesn't explain the problem using this with mutable objects, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye: lists are mutable objects just as much as dicts are.

Comment: @thefourtheye: We'd be better off closing this as a dupe of [Unexpected feature in a Python list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/240178) then.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [{'elem' : 0}] * 2
```

'a' contains two references to the same dictionary. The equivalent of the first case would be:

```
a[0] = {'elem' : 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using multiplication, you created list of references to the same dictionary

```
In [11]: a = [{'elem' : 0}] * 2
In [14]: for elem in a:
    print id(elem)
   ....:     
142676420
142676420
```

To create list of 2 independent dictionaries

```
In [15]: a = [{'elem' : 0} for _ in range(2)]

In [16]: for elem in a:
    print id(elem)
   ....:     
142695116
142695932
```